# use of private method inside abstract class

Tags: java

What is the use of writing a private method inside an abstract class, and can we write public static inside that class? Please give an example.

Comment: Have you tried creating a private method in an abstract class? What happens? There's your answer

Comment: sounds like a homework, if yes tag it with homework keyword as well

Answer (score 9):

You can use any kind of method in an abstract class. The only difference between an abstract class and a normal one is that the abstract class contains methods which have no body:

```
 public abstract Foo {
     public void foo() {
          bar();
     }

     private void bar() {
          doSomething();
     }

     protected abstract void doSomething();
 }
```

So while `bar()` has no idea what `doSomething()` really does, it knows that it will exist eventually and how to call it.

This is enough for the compiler to create the byte code for the class.

Answer (score 4):

we can have our implementation in abstract class and so the private method

For Example :

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO{

public void save(){
  validate();
  //save
}

  private void validate(){ // we are hiding this method
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

But an abstract method can never be private , it must be public or protected , otherwise the subclass won't be able to define it

Comment: He's not exclusively talking about abstract methods.